# How to batch append subdirectory to link target in bash

Tags: bash, symlink, batch-rename

I have a directory under my control with a lot of symbolic links to sub-directories in another directory not under my control. The "format" has recently changed, and I would like to update all my symbolic links to append "new" to the link target.

Example of the current situation:

> - u -> /catalog/uvw
> - v -> /catalog/uvw
> - x -> /catalog/xyz
> - y -> /catalog/xyz
> - ...

How can I batch-append a subdirectory to each link target, so that the new links have the following targets?

> - u -> /catalog/uvw/new
> - v -> /catalog/uvw/new
> - x -> /catalog/xyz/new
> - y -> /catalog/xyz/new
> - ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
find . -type l -maxdepth 1 -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d "" link; do
    target="$(readlink "$link")"
    ln -nfs "$target/new" "$link"
done
```

Hope this helps.